# Pygame colliderect constant collisions?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

Thanks BlackJack, here's the code with your suggestion. The player image just stays in the top-left corne (0,0). The image cycles through those in the runner array, but pressing left or right does not make the player sprite move at the edge of the background image, or move the background image and blocks.

```
import pygame, math
from math import *


backimage = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Jed/Desktop/Drawings/DSC_0001_cropped.jpg")
cameraX_offset = 0
cameraY_offset = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700,700])

pygame.init()
pygame.key.set_repeat(20, 20)

#Runner instances#
runner = []
#lots of images from disk add to array
currentRunner = 17
#end of runners!#



freespeed = 5   #speed character moves at edges of background
jumping = False
jumpingLeft = True
jumpVariable = 0
initialY = None

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = runner[int(floor(currentRunner))]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (350, 500)

    def see_on_block(self):
        new_rect = self.rect.move(0, 2)
        if not any(new_rect.colliderect(b.rect) for b in blocks):
                self.rect= new_rect

    def movement (self):
        global cameraX_offset, currentRunner, jumping, jumpingLeft, jumpVariable, initialY
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:                  #moving character left
                    if cameraX_offset <= 0 and self.rect.left > 20:     
                        self.rect.left -= freespeed
                    elif 350 < self.rect.left <= 800:
                        self.rect.left -= freespeed
                    elif cameraX_offset > 0:
                        cameraX_offset -=1
                    if currentRunner >= 7:
                        currentRunner = 0
                    else:
                        currentRunner += 0.3

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                 #moving character right
                    if cameraX_offset >= 250 and self.rect.left < 635:
                        self.rect.left += freespeed
                    elif -10 <= self.rect.left < 350:
                        self.rect.left += freespeed
                    elif cameraX_offset < 250:
                        cameraX_offset += 1
                    if currentRunner < 8 or



currentRunner >= 15:
                        currentRunner = 8
                    else:
                        currentRunner += 0.3

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    jumping = True
                    initialY = self.rect.top

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if 0 <= currentRunner <= 7:
                        currentRunner = 16
                    elif 8 <= currentRunner <= 15:
                        currentRunner = 17

        if jumping == True:
            if 0 <= currentRunner <= 7 or currentRunner == 16 or 18 <= currentRunner <= 21: #sees whether character is facing left or right when jump initiated
                jumpingLeft = True
            else:
                jumpingLeft = False
            jumpVariable += (radians(5))

            if radians(90) <= jumpVariable < radians(270):
                self.rect.top = initialY - 100*sin(jumpVariable - radians(90))  #moves character in Y according to sin
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    if cameraX_offset <= 0 and self.rect.left > 20:         #moves character in X if facing left
                        self.rect.left -= jumpVariable
                    elif 350 < self.rect.left <= 800:
                        self.rect.left -= jumpVariable
                    elif cameraX_offset > 0:
                        cameraX_offset -= 2
                elif jumpingLeft == False:
                    if cameraX_offset >= 250 and self.rect.left < 635:      #moves character in X if facing right
                        self.rect.left += jumpVariable
                    elif -10 <= self.rect.left < 350:
                        self.rect.left += jumpVariable
                    elif cameraX_offset < 250:
                        cameraX_offset += 2

            if jumpVariable >= radians(270):                        #changes character's sprite when jumping according to variable
                jumping = False
                jumpVariable = 0
            if  0 < jumpVariable < radians(45):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 18
                else:
                    currentRunner = 22
            elif radians(45) <= jumpVariable < radians(70):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 19
                else:
                    currentRunner = 23
            elif radians(70) <= jumpVariable < radians (105):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 20
                else:
                    currentRunner = 24
            elif radians(105) <= jumpVariable < radians (225):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 21
                else:
                    currentRunner = 25
            elif radians(225) <= jumpVariable <= radians(260):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 18
                else:
                    currentRunner = 22
            elif radians(260) < jumpVariable < radians(270):
                if jumpingLeft == True:
                    currentRunner = 16
                else:
                    currentRunner = 17

        if jumping == False:
            jumpVariable = 0

        self.image = runner[int(floor(currentRunner))]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.left, self.rect.top))


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, blockX, blockY, block_width, block_height):
        self.blockX = blockX
        self.blockY = blockY
        self.block_width = block_width
        self.block_height = block_height

    def draw_block(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,[160, 160, 160], (self.blockX - 2*cameraX_offset, self.blockY - cameraY_offset, self.block_width, self.block_height))


##create object instances##
blocks = []
floorBlock = Block (0, 680, 1200, 20)
blocks.append(floorBlock)
leftWall = Block (0 , 0, 20, 700)
blocks.append(leftWall)
rightWall = Block (1180 , 0, 20, 700)
blocks.append(rightWall)
block1 = Block (450, 600, 100, 20)
blocks.append(block1)
player = Player()


##main loop##
running = True    
while running:

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.blit(backimage, (0-cameraX_offset, 0-cameraY_offset))

    for b in blocks:
        b.draw_block()


    player.movement()
    player.see_on_block()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In the next to last line of `Player.movement()` you are overwriting `self.rect` with the image's `Rect` instance which is _always_ located at (0, 0). For blitting you can just use the `Rect` instance itself by the way.  No need to extract x and y from it.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code where you set the rectangle to the player is what matters. You initially set the rectangle of the runner to be the same as the one of the image, which turns out to be (0, 0, width, height).

Because the runner is moving around, you have to take its position into account and in your see_on_block modify the position of the rectangle (the first two values of a rect).

```
    def see_on_block(self):
    self.Y += 2
    tempRect = (self.rect[0] + self.X, self.rect[1] + self.Y, self.rect[2], self.rect[3]);
    for b in blocks:
        if b.rect.colliderect(tempRect):
                self.Y -= 2
                break
```

I'd recommend you use the first two values in self.rect as the position instead of self.X and self.Y and modify your code where needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works great! However, what does the self.rect[0, 1, 2, 3] refer to?

Comment: A rect has these 4 different values that can be used: rect[0] refers to the x position of the rectangle, rect[1] refers to the y position of the rectangle, rect[2] refers to the width, and rect[3] refers to the height of the rectangle. It's better to just use the attributes of a rect, so rather than calling rect[1] you should call rect.y etc. See https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html for the attributes and methods.

Comment: That line can be written as `tempRect = self.rect.move(self.X, self.Y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `X` and `Y` attribute and use the `rect` attribute to store position and size of the sprite.  That's how it's supposed to be used.  `Rect` objects have a bunch of methods and attributes to move them around and get the coordinates and positions if the points and sides.

So the first two methods of your `Player` class may look like this:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = runner[int(floor(currentRunner))]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (350, 500)

    def see_on_block(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        for b in blocks:
            if self.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
                self.rect.y -= 2
                break
```

This last method can be expressed a little more compact and without the subtraction:

```
    def see_on_block(self):
        new_rect = self.rect.move(0, 2)
        if not any(new_rect.colliderect(b.rect) for b in blocks):
            self.rect = new_rect
```

If you use Pygame's sprite groups instead of a list you can replace the `if` condition with a call to [pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany).

Comment: Hi BlackJack, thanks for the help. I have tried to use your suggestion, but when I run the program, the runner sprite is stuck at position (0,0) on the canvas, and although pressing the keys makes the sprite image cycles through the instances for animation when running and jumping, the sprite does not move left or right when at the edges of the background image, nor does the backgroun image move. I have edited the original post to include the updated code. Thanks!